# jasper replace String code

Tags: replace, jasper-reports

I have a string variable wich contain only one letter like "D" or "A" etc ...
I want to replace this letter by an explicit text but when I do (in this case "$F{Action}" contain "D"):

```
$F{Action}.replace('D','Apple').replace('A','text')
```

my result is "textpple" Because Apple beggin with an "A" and my second replace is on the letter "A"

How can I do to only replace the letter by the firt replace statment and not do the others replace statement?

Comment: Can you clearly explain your question? What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: One way do things like this is to do the first replace to a temporary placeholder string that will not occur in your texts (like '$$%%$$'), and at the end replace that with the 'Apple' (i.e. adding a third replace).

Comment: I don't understand what you said @JanDoggen 

I think the better way to do what I want is to make a scriplet, does anybody know how to do this ?

Comment: @viki888 My input is (in this case) "D" and I want to replace this letter with "Apple" and if its not "D" but "A" I also want to replace this "A" with "text". So my expected output is "Apple" (D->Apple) but my result is "textpple" 

I think the better way to do what I want is to make a scriplet, does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of scriptlet for this small work. You can try using the below expression

```
$F{Action}.contains( "D" ) ? "Apple" : $F{Action}.contains( "A" ) ? "text" : ""
```

Hope this is your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not work :/
I've tried with "replaceFirst" and "replaceAll" but it does not work, same result as "replace"